# Collection View Cell Size Is Not As Expected

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard using storyboard. I need to use two collection views. I want the height and width of collection view cell as the height of collection view itself. Constraints are set properly. But cell size is not looking as expected. It is same as what height collection view has on the storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Simulator]

Here is the code.

```
        #import "MainViewController.h"
        #import "UpperCollectionViewCell.h"
        #import "LowerCollectionViewCell.h"

        @interface MainViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *upperCollectionView;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *lowerCollectionView;

        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *upperData;
        @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *lowerData;

        @end

        @implementation MainViewController

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSLog(@"View Presented");

        self.lowerCollectionView.delegate = self;
        self.lowerCollectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.upperCollectionView.delegate = self;
        self.upperCollectionView.dataSource = self;

        self.upperData = @[[[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bollywood" subtitle:nil color:[UIColor orangeColor]],
                       [[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hollywood" subtitle:nil color:[UIColor greenColor]],
                       [[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tollywood" subtitle:nil color:[UIColor magentaColor]]];

        self.lowerData = @[[[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"News" subtitle:@"Very first comment" color:[UIColor blueColor]],
                       [[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tasks" subtitle:@"Second comment" color:[UIColor redColor]],
                       [[DataModel alloc] initWithTitle:@"Events" subtitle:@"Third comment" color:[UIColor greenColor]]];

        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
        return 1;
        }

        - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if(collectionView == self.lowerCollectionView) {

        return self.lowerData.count;
        }

        else if(collectionView == self.upperCollectionView) {

        return self.upperData.count;
        }
        else {
        return 0;
        }
        }

        - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(collectionView == self.lowerCollectionView) {

        LowerCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"lower_cv_cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setDataModel:self.lowerData[indexPath.row]];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        return cell;
        }

        else if(collectionView == self.upperCollectionView) {

        UpperCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"upper_cv_cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setDataModel:self.upperData[indexPath.row]];
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        return cell;

        }
        else {
        return nil;
        }
        }

        - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if(collectionView == self.lowerCollectionView) {

        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.height, collectionView.bounds.size.height-10);

        NSLog(@"lower height : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));

        return size;
        }

        else if(collectionView == self.upperCollectionView) {

        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.height, collectionView.bounds.size.height-10);
        NSLog(@"upper height : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(size));
        return size;
        }
        else {
        return CGSizeZero;
        }
        }

        @end
```

Unable to figure out why cell size is not as expected.

Comment: Is this statement printing the right size NSLog(@"upper height : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(size)); ?

Comment: Yes, and it is what height has on the storyboard.

Comment: I know the way I'm doing is correct. It works well when I do it with regular UIViewController. But it is not working in the case of UIInputViewController on CustomKeyboard.